# How to handle a simple IRQ on RPI 2 bare metal

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, bare-metal

I have been trying to handle a simple IRQ from the emulated RPI 2 with QEMU but wasn't successful :/

Here is my code:
http://lpaste.net/586201347288727552

On the C side all I do is printing a "Hello world" on the serial port then run a simple loop

My C handler prints "Hello IRQ" the same way "Hello world" is printed

Anyone seeing an error or could give me some pointers ?

Thanks,
Merwan

Comment: https://xkcd.com/138/

Comment: Don't you get any complaints about 'irq_interrupt_handler_c' not defined as an 'extern'? Also, what triggers your interrupt, and does the serial use interrupt too?

Comment: If your serial uses IRQ to print out stuff, remember that you disable IRQ before calling the C code. You also overwrite the serial interrupt vector in that case.

Comment: No I don't have any complains. Isn't the IRQ supposed to trigger itself ? That's what my teacher told me ...
Even if I disable IRQ beforing printing stuff, it is printing what I want